# how to let pre-specified numbers of agents staying at an area at the beginning of simulation waiting for pick up?

Tags: anylogic, agent

I would like to specify a fix numbers of agents that are shown at the beginning of the simulation so I can move them to the other place. However, the agents are generated continuously... Do you know how to make a pre-specified population and let them wait at an area instead of generating them continuously ??

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Set the source properties as follows:
[image]

Then, in the on startup field of main, type the following code:

```
source.inject(50);
```

[image]

Comment: yes, but the agents are still generated "continuously". I hope to see them all at the beginning in an area, and simulate them to the other place. For example, I want to see 50 people waiting in a room and then I can let them move to another place.

Comment: I see, then you need to use the inject function, I will update my answer.